# Extracting Numbers From Between String

Tags: c#, regex

What's the best way to extract the number part from this string? I looked at RegularExpressions but they confuse the hell out of me. Is it possible with SubString?

```
/store/457987680928164?id=2
```

All I require is the numbers.

Comment: Only the first (large) number, and not the second? Could the strings have more than the two path segments you've shown above?

Comment: Would you like to extract 457987680928164 or 579876809281642 ?

Comment: It's the large number I require. And no the strings only have 1 path segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegEx is a good way to go with this problem, but if you're set on using SubString...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string test = "/store/457987680928164?id=2";
            int start = test.IndexOfAny("0123456789".ToCharArray());
            int end = test.IndexOf("?");

            Console.WriteLine(test.Substring(start, end - start));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect for what I require.

Answer (score 0):

You should get RadExpression Designer and teach yourself RegEx's with the cheat sheets.

If RegEx's frighten you, simply do it in a loop which will often be quicker:

```
string s = "/store/457987680928164?id=2";
string numericInput = string.Empty;
foreach(char c in s)
{
   if (char.IsDigit(c))
       numericInput  += c;
}
```

Comment: This would pick up all the digits, so it would be trailed by the last "2" in this example

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend using RegEx for this.  String pattern matching and extraction is really an ideal scenario for Regular Expressions.

Here is a RegEx that will match the string sample you provided, with capturing parenthesis for the numeric parts of the String:

```
^/store/(\d+)\?id=(\d+)
```

You can verify it here in the [**Regex Tester**](http://regexpal.com/).  I tested it using your sample String and the RegEx I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer Regex, this isn't using substring runs faster than it in my examples

```
static long GrabFirstLongFromString(string input)
{
    string intAsString = String.Empty;
    bool startedInt = false;
    foreach(char c in input)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c))
        {
            startedInt = true; //really only care about the first digit
            intAsString += c;
        }
        else if (startedInt)
            return long.Parse(intAsString);
    }
    return -1; //define a default, since this only does a 0 or positive I picked a negative
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it with regular expressions

```
private static Regex digitsOnly = new Regex(@"[^\d]");

        public static string RemoveNonNumbers(string input)
        {
            return digitsOnly.Replace(input, "");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just simple Regex:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\d+");
MatchCollection m = r.Matches("/store/457987680928164?id=2");

if (m.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Big number: {0} - Little number: {1}", m[0], m[1]));
}
```

The above prints:

```
Big number: 457987680928164 - Little number: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with these extension methods to simplify common string parsing tasks:

```
private static string Substring(string str, string value, bool isLastValue, bool isAfterValue, StringComparison comparisonType, string defaultValue)
{
    int pos = isLastValue ? str.LastIndexOf(value, comparisonType) : str.IndexOf(value, comparisonType);
    if (pos == -1) return defaultValue;
    return isAfterValue ? str.Substring(pos + value.Length) : str.Substring(0, pos);
}

public static string SubstringBeforeFirst(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return Substring(str, value, false, false, comparisonType, defaultValue);
}

public static string SubstringBeforeLast(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return Substring(str, value, true, false, comparisonType, defaultValue);
}

public static string SubstringAfterFirst(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return Substring(str, value, false, true, comparisonType, defaultValue);
}

public static string SubstringAfterLast(this string str, string value, StringComparison comparisonType = StringComparison.CurrentCulture, string defaultValue = "")
{
    return Substring(str, value, true, true, comparisonType, defaultValue);
}
```

As for getting the number from your example:

```
string s = "/store/457987680928164?id=2";
string number = s.SubstringAfterLast("/").SubstringBeforeFirst("?");
```

Answer (score 0):

YARS  (Yet Another Regex Solution)

The following:

```
var str = "/store/457987680928164?id=2";

var regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(str))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

outputs this:

```
457987680928164
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string str = "/store/457987680928164?id=2";
 string num = new string(str.Remove(str.IndexOf("?")).Where(a => char.IsDigit(a)).ToArray());
```